# Use global variable in xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am working with **xsd files** and I have this CommandText:

```
 <CommandText> SELECT DISTINCT CODLANZA
  FROM            TC_LANZA_PEDLIN
  WHERE        (CODEMP = '3') AND (TIPOREG = 'cf') AND (NUMPED = @numped)
  ORDER BY CODLANZA </CommandText>
```

And **I would like to use in (CODEMP = '3') this: enterprise.enterpriseID that is a variable in a global project**. So the CommandText would be something like this:

```
 <CommandText> SELECT DISTINCT CODLANZA
  FROM            TC_LANZA_PEDLIN
  WHERE        (CODEMP = 'enterprise.enterpriseID') AND (TIPOREG = 'cf') AND (NUMPED = @numped)
  ORDER BY CODLANZA </CommandText>
```

Is my first time working with this and I am so lost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Command test is a string and can't be modified.  So 3 is a default value.  You would need to use REGEX to modified the Command text string to change to a different value.  This looks like a query for a SQL Server.  So parameters for the query can be substituted.  You would use @enterpriseID and then add the parameter to the SQL Command.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your help! yes, is a query for a SQL server where CodEmp can be 3, 5 or 7. And I have in a global variable called enterprise.enterpriseID the actual value of CodEmp and I would like to use this variable to use the correct enterprise, not only the enterprise 3.

Comment: XSD will not do dynamic replacement when reading.  XSD is just a schema that gives format and type of an item.  The values are usually in the xml file.  You can have embedded schema in xml, but not opposite (data in xsd).  So when generating the xsd you would need to do the replacements.

Comment: @jdweng so I have to do this in other file? For example, the name is project_order.xsd and this project_order.xsd contains three files: project_order.Designer.cs / project_order.xsc / project_order.xss

Comment: Why does a project have an xsd extension?  xsd are schema files used to validate xml files.  Now c# project files csproj are xml format but I've never seen a schema written for the checking of the project file.  It is possible, but strange.

Comment: @jdweng no sorry, is not a project is just a xsd that contains these 3 files. But is a simple xsd in a project.

Comment: As I said you need to add parameters to your Command Text.  Then add the parameters to your SQL Command(s).

Comment: The abbreviation (and certainly the SO tag) "xsd" generally refers to W3C XML Schema. I suspect you are using it to mean something else, and this is getting people confused. Well, it's certainly getting me confused...